# What is the preferred way to handle multiple test cases in Xunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, xunit, xunit.net

I have migrated to using Xunit for unit tests from NUnit.  With NUnit, I would create one method with multiple test cases that have the same outcome. For example, the following NUnit unit test tests the validation of a class constructor, specifically the "name" variable.  The name can't be null, empty or whitespace.  The test checks that an ArgumentNullException is correctly thrown:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase(null)]
    [TestCase("")]
    [TestCase("     ")]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Constructor_InvalidName_ExceptionThrown(string name)
    {
        // action
        make_Foo(name);
    }

    private make_Foo(string name)
    {
        return new Foo(name);
    }
```

This is how I have implemented this using Xunit:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Constructor_InvalidName_ExceptionThrown()
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Foo(null));
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Foo(""));
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Foo("    "));
    }
```

This seems bad for two reasons - I have multiple Asserts in what is supposed to be a "unit" test, and with the test cases buried within the method (which could get a lot more complicated in some of the other unit tests).

What is the preferred way to handle multiple test cases in Xunit?

Comment: XUnit has a type called `Theory` that you can use.

Comment: For an example of XUnit's Theory attribute: look [here](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Creating-Inline-Data-Driven-Tests-in-xUnit.aspx)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the [`Theory`](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata) attribute to the same effect:

```
[Theory()]
[InlineData(null)]
[InlineData("")]
[InlineData("     ")]
public void Constructor_InvalidName_ExceptionThrown(string name)
{
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Foo(name));
}
```

---

<strike>I am not sure if xUnit has am attribute equivalent to `ExpectedException` however. If there is, [I would not use it](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2012/09/26/be-careful-when-using-junit-expected-exceptions/).</strike>

There **used** to be an  `ExpectedException` attribute in xUnit but it has since been [deprecated in favour of `Assert.Throws`](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html#note1).

Comment: Theory link is broken